# Is it possible to store files uploaded on your website to google drive?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

We have our company website and we  have many job opportunities often. So we have created a form where in interested candidates can apply directly. We also have a resume upload facility, right now resumes are uploaded and stored using `PHP` this resumes are stores onto our server, but we don't want to waste server space so we were thinking to just create one dedicated folder for resumes on Google drive and whenever user uploads his resume from our web site it will get stores onto a Google drive folder. Is this possible. We don't want to do it with Google forms or form+ since we have form matching our website theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to integrate into your website the Google Drive SDK which can allow you to do just that. You should look here for the PHP [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php#saving_new_files).

So yes, you can directly store the documents on the Google Drive using the API provided [here.](https://developers.google.com/drive/) Look over [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads) to access the more specifics for file uploading.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible with the php google class.
a very good example you can get from: http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001954.html

Comment: in that tutorial its said as i need to create an web app , is it mandatory ? to create a web app because i don't know anything about it